# Binding a foreign key when adding a new value to the master-detail table Delphi

Tags: sql, database, delphi, delphi-7

There are 2 tables linked by master-detail. When adding a new value to the detail table, the foreign key selected from the master table is not bound.

The M-D connection itself is performed on the form using two Dblookupcombobox and DataSource, ADOQuery for each, respectively.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzR3f.png)

Using the [ + ] buttons, new values are added that are not present in the combobox. But the problems start at the second [ + ] (aka detail), when creating a new line, you need it to bind the foreign key from the previous LookUpComboBox (Master). Button code of the second button [+]:

```
begin
Form4.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
Form4.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Select City from City WHERE   City='+#39+Form5.DBEdit1.Text+#39); //checking for duplicates
Form4.ADOQuery1.Open;
if Form4.ADOQuery1.IsEmpty then
  begin
  Form4.Query_city.FieldByName('City').AsString := Form5.DBEdit1.Text; //The PROBLEM is  SOMEWHERE HERE! It Adds a new value without binding the foreign key
  Form4.Query_city.Open;
  Form4.Query_city.Post;
  MessageBox(Handle, 'New data entered','Adding a new value',MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  end
 else
  begin
  Form4.Query_spec.Cancel;
  Form4.ADOQuery1.Cancel;
  MessageBox(Handle,PChar(''+Form5.DBEdit1.text+' already on the list!'),'Error',MB_ICONWARNING);
  end;
 end;
```

The new value is written to DBEdit1. It has a corresponding binding to tables.
So How i can insert field with with the corresponding foreign key?

Comment: I'm afraid the code in your `if Form4.AdoQuery1...` block is completely wrong - you cannot correctly set Query_city's City field until it is open and then you may need to do an Insert.  Find yourself a Master-Detail tutorial - that should explain the correct steps and the order of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making this unneccessarily difficult because of the way your
code is structured. Try something like this instead:

Open ADOQuery1, SELECTing its entire contents, with e.g.

```
procedure TForm4.OpenCitiesTable;
begin
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Select City from City');
  ADOQuery1.Open;
end;
```

and leave it open while the user does whatever operations lead to wanting to add a new city.

Then, when the users wants to add a city, call this procedure, e.g. supplying the City
value from Form5.DBEdit1.Text.

```
procedure TForm4.AddCity(ACity : String);
begin
  ACity := Trim(ACity);  // remove any leading or trailing blanks
  //  Do any formatting checks on ACity here, re.g convert it to Proper case

  //  check for adding a duplicate
  if ADOQuery1.Locate('City', ACity, []) then begin
    ShowMessageFmt('%s is already in the City table', [ACity]);
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    ADOQuery1.Insert;
    ADOQuery1.FieldByName('City').AsString := ACity;
  finally
    ADOQuery1.Post;
    //  at this point you might want to refresh the contents of whatever source
    //  you are populating Form5.DBEdit1.Text from
  end;
end;
```

I assume you can adjust the code relating to TForm4.Query_spec yourself;

Btw, you might want to consider using a TDBLookUpComboBox instead of your DBEdit1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I realize that I'm reinventing the wheel, because I only recently started working for Delphi. Can you tell me how best to use "insert"?

Comment: In theory, M-D communication works, since I can scroll through a list of specific cities by selecting a specific country. That's why I created a separate form to add new cities to it. When trying to run the "Form4.Query_City.Insert;" it adds a new entry to the "Cities" table and even assigns it a new primary key, but does not add the foreign key of the country. In theory, I was thinking of doing something like this: Insert into Cities (City,Country_id //foreign key) VALUES ( from Form5.DBEdit1.Text, Form4.DBLookupcombobox_country);

Comment: Well, `Insert` is simple - see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Insert - you just call it, set any field values you want and then call .Post on the dataset.  When doing an Insert on a Sql query result, it's up to you to ensure that the new record's field values satisfy the conditions in the WHERE clause.  Btw. it's bad practice to enter a new record in one table while you are in the middle of editing or inserting a record in another table, whether they are a master-detail or not.  Do one, **then** do the other.

Comment: Thx. I used something like this: Form4.Query_City.FieldByName('City').AsString := Form5.DBEdit1.Text;
  Form4.Query_city.fieldbyname('Country_ID').AsInteger:= Form4.Query_Country.FieldByName('id_countrytable').asInteger;